# Listbox selection gets reset when an option from Combobox is selected

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Listbox for selecting multiple values and Combobox to select one option from a list of options. If i select some value(s) from Listbox and then go ahead and select some value from Combobox, then my Listbox selection gets reset.

Refer the below code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class CheckboxDropdownApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('List box with Scrollbar and Dropdown')

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        # Create a frame to hold the Listbox, Scrollbar, and Combobox
        frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        frame.pack()

        # Create a Listbox with a scrollbar
        self.box = tk.Listbox(frame, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE, height=4)
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.box.yview)

        self.box.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        values = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Purple', 'Yellow', 'Orange', 'Black', 'White']
        for val in values:
            # Add padding to each item
            padded_val = f"   {val}   "
            self.box.insert(tk.END, padded_val)

        self.box.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        # Create a Combobox
        self.dropdown_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.dropdown = ttk.Combobox(frame, values=values, textvariable=self.dropdown_var)
        self.dropdown.set(values[0])
        self.dropdown.pack(pady=10)

        # Create buttons
        show_button = tk.Button(self.master, text='Show', width=25, command=self.clicked)
        show_button.pack()

        close_button = tk.Button(self.master, text='Close', width=25, command=self.master.destroy)
        close_button.pack()

    def clicked(self):
        selected = self.box.curselection()  # returns a tuple
        dropdown_value = self.dropdown_var.get()

        if not selected and not dropdown_value:
            print("No item selected.")
        else:
            print("Selected items:")
            for idx in selected:
                print(self.box.get(idx).strip())  # Remove padding when printing
            print(f"Dropdown selected value: {dropdown_value}")

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = CheckboxDropdownApp(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Please let me know how can i resolve this.